# Better way to format CASE containing multiple nested SELECTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

I want to do this:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (
case when 
    (select date from history where statut='X' and id=6 order by date desc limit 1) 
     is null then now() 
  else 
    (select date from history where statut='X' and id=6 order by date desc limit 1) end)
- case when 
    (select date from history where statut in ('Y', 'U') and id=6 order by date desc limit 1) 
     is null then now() 
else 
 (select date from history where statut in ('Y', 'U')  and id=6 order by date desc limit 1) 
 end 
)/3600)
```

This request search in history date of modification for certain statuts, subtracts it, and returns difference in hours. 
In case no line is found it should be replaced by 0.

It works but we can all see how ugly it is.

Is there a way to beautify my query?

Comment: A simpler way to do it is to make the subquery as a table without the `statut in ('Y', 'U')` filter and use only it in your case statement... that way it will be better and run that query only once.

Comment: It would be better to tell us what you are trying to achieve with that.  **[Edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simplification:

```
case when X is null
  then Y
  else X
end
```

can be written as:

```
coalesce(X, Y)
```

This reduces your query to:

```
SELECT (
  EXTRACT(epoch FROM 
    coalesce((select date from history where statut='X' and id=6 order by date desc limit 1), now())
     -
    coalesce((select date from history where statut in ('Y', 'U') and id=6 order by date desc limit 1), now())
  ) / 3600
)
```

Another simplification:

```
select X from T order by X desc limit 1
```

is just:

```
select max(X) from T
```

Yielding:

```
SELECT (
  EXTRACT(epoch FROM 
    coalesce((select max(date) from history where statut='X' and id=6), now())
     -
    coalesce((select max(date) from history where statut in ('Y', 'U') and id=6), now())
  ) / 3600
)
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you